# Running systemctl with 'clean' command doesn't find my service

Tags: linux, systemctl

I tried to run the following:

```
sudo systemctl clean --what=configuration myService
```

And got the error:

```
Failed to clean unit myService.service: Unit is not inactive or has pending job.
```

So I tried to inactivate `myService` and then run the clean command again:

```
sudo systemctl stop myService
sudo systemctl clean --what=configuration myService
```

And got the following error:

```
Failed to clean unit myService.service: No matching resources found.
```

How could it be that the resource wasn't found, if I succeed in stopping it?
How can I run `systemctl clean --what=configuration` properly?